# Suppose that elements $a, b$ and $a+b$ are units in a commutative ring $R$. Show that $a^{-1} + b^{-1}$ is also a unit.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Suppose that elements $a, b$ and $a+b$ are units in a commutative ring $R$. Show that $a^{-1} + b^{-1}$ is also a unit.

Here is what I have:

$a+b =b+a$ since $R$ is commutative.

Now,

$$(b+a) \cdot b^{-1} = 1+ab^{-1} \\
a^{-1} \cdot (1+ab^{-1}) = a^{-1} + b^{-1}
$$

Thus, $a^{-1} + b^{-1} =a^{-1} \cdot (a+b) \cdot b^{-1}$

Therefore, $(a^{-1} + b^{-1})^{-1} = b \cdot (a+b)^{-1} \cdot a$

And thus, $a^{-1} + b^{-1}$ is a unit in $R$ as well.

Does my answer sound logical. Or are there errors in it?

Answer (score 3):

Your answer works perfectly fine.  In fact, your answer works in *non-commutative* rings as well.

When we say that a ring is commutative, we mean $ab = ba$.  We will have $a + b = b + a$ is *any* ring.

Comment: How then is the fact that this ring is commutative relevant in this problem?

Comment: In fact, it's irrelevant.  It does make the proof a bit easier, though, since we can now write $ab(a^{-1} + b^{-1}) = a + b$.

Comment: Well thanks for reminding me that commutativity in rings refer to commutative multiplication. My brain really floats away from me sometimes. I always knew that rings are abelian groups as well :/

Answer (score 2):

Your proof is fine.

One way to discover it is by computing freely:
$$
\frac{1}{\dfrac{1}{a}+\dfrac{1}{b}}
=
\frac{1}{\dfrac{a+b}{ab}}
=
\frac{ab}{a+b}
$$